# Взаимодействие Winforms и WPF, как организовать?

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2015, vb.net

Есть приложение которое состоит из нескольких частей Winforms + несколько библиотек классов. Библиотеки классов включают не только обычные классы, модули, юзерконтролы но и формы. Как интегрировать в данное приложение WPF форму? Хотелось бы в виде отдельной библиотеки, но почемуто добавление WPF форм недоступно.

Comment: Мне встречались только примеры, когда в WPF внедрялись контролы Winforms, а вот обратное, вряд ли возможно. Да и зачем в принципе это нужно?

Comment: Можно в обе стороны, вот пример https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfxMoyy2D1k

Comment: @S.Kost Мне кажется что в моем проекте запрещено использовать WPF ибо при добавлении указанным на видео способом, элемент не появляется на панели инструментов... И при ручном добавлении нжного элемента пишет что он типа добавился но не включился из за настроек проекта.

Comment: http://clip2net.com/s/3Eey9nk